# R glm() Output function in r

Tags: r, logistic

Below is the function and the output of glm() function in r. My question is why the output of the predictor variables contains one factor level for example MaritalStatusMarried, instead of MaritalStatus only. My predictor variable "MaritalStatus" had two levels,"Single" and "Married"

[image]

Comment: `MaritalStatusSingle` is the baseline and is included in the intercept. `MaritalStatusMarried` is the "effect" of being Married rather than Single.

Comment: Okay, so there's no way I can remove that from the output?

Comment: What do you want to remove?

Comment: I want the output to be like **MaritalStatus** and not **MaritalStatusMarried**

Comment: You are probably looking for the output from `library(car); Anova(StudentModel)` .  You may also want to look at the `emmeans` package.

Comment: The only way to get an output with just `MaritalStatus` would be to using `anova`. However, you will not get an estimate for the effect; the only common information will be p-value